# Why does my Ubuntu 20.04 installation sometimes hang on booting?

Tags: boot, 20.04

Sometimes (I would guess in about 25% of the cases) my new Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installation freezes during the boot process.

These are the last messages that are shown in the console when this happens:

```
[  OK  ] Started Snap Daemon.
Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
[  OK  ] Finished Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
[  OK  ] Finished resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> to initiate a reboot. The system is going down, but displays the following message:

```
[  *** ] A stop job is running for Light Display Manager (35s / 1min 30s)
```

This is quite unusual. I haven't seen this message before. I don't know if the two things are related.

Does anybody have any ideas what could be the problem here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can sometimes happen when there is a conflict between `systemd` and the Intel display drivers. I haven't seen this particular issue for years, but you should be able to fix it with a little workaround:

1. create a file as `root` named `/etc/sysctl.d/50-coredump.conf`
2. Paste:
   `kernel.core_pattern=core`
3. Reboot

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you. I applied the changes and will report back in a few days/reboots whether the issue has been resolved or not.

Comment: I haven't experienced the issue again, so this seems to have solved the problem. Thanks you very much.